# How to create a button to end the program without ending the GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI to have a test bench be more user friendly but they have requested a stop button that will end the current program without killing the actual GUI window.

I understand that threading may be the way to do it since when the 'start' button is pressed, it takes over the whole GUI window and nothing can be clicked but I am unsure of how to actually implement it in my code.

I expect to be able to press the stop button and have the GPIOs return to their off state and then be able to hit the start button again and have the program restart at the beginning again.

```
import tkinter as tk
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time as time
from time import sleep                                                           

#sets GPIO pin numbers#
GPIO4 = 4
GPIO17 = 17
GPIO27 = 27
GPIO22 = 22
GPIO23 = 23
GPIO24 = 24

#sets the initial state of the start button#
Start_state = True

#sets GPIOs to GPIO pin numbers#
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#sets warnings to not show#
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#sets up GPIOs as outputs#
GPIO.setup(GPIO4, GPIO.OUT)                                                      
GPIO.setup(GPIO17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO27, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO24, GPIO.OUT)

#sets initial states of the pins#
GPIO.output(GPIO4, False)                                                                
GPIO.output(GPIO17, False)
GPIO.output(GPIO27, False)
GPIO.output(GPIO22, False)
GPIO.output(GPIO23, False)
GPIO.output(GPIO24, False)

#start of main.loop()#
try:

####sets GUI window####
    master = tk.Tk()

####name of GUI####
    master.title("SOLENOID CONTROL")

####sets size of window (widthxheight)####
    master.geometry  ("650x150")                                                    

####sets initial states of GPIOs to 'off'####
    GPIO4_state = False
    GPIO17_state = False
    GPIO27_state = False
    GPIO22_state = False
    GPIO23_state = False
    GPIO24_state = False                                                          

####defines checkbutton states and relates them to individual GPIOs####
    def GPIO4button():                                                            
        global GPIO4_state
        GPIO4_state = not GPIO4_state

    def GPIO17button():                                                           
        global GPIO17_state
        GPIO17_state = not GPIO17_state

    def GPIO27button():                                                           
        global GPIO27_state
        GPIO27_state = not GPIO27_state

    def GPIO22button():                                                           
        global GPIO22_state
        GPIO22_state = not GPIO22_state

    def GPIO23button():                                                          
        global GPIO23_state
        GPIO23_state = not GPIO23_state

    def GPIO24button():                                                           
        global GPIO24_state
        GPIO24_state = not GPIO24_state

####defines dwell, spray times, and number of repititions (runs) from entry boxes####
    def dwell():
        dwell = e1.get()

    def spray():
        spray = e2.get()

    def runs():
        runs = e3.get()

####defines the start buttons actions####
    def Start():

########gets input from entry boxes to be used in while loop#########
        dwell = int(e1.get())
        print('dwell: ' + str(dwell))
        if e1.get() == 0:
            time.sleep(e1.get())
        else:
            pass

        spray = int(e2.get())
        print('spray: ' + str(spray))
        if e2.get() == 0:
            time.sleep(e2.get())
        else:
            pass

        runs = int(e3.get())
        print('runs: ' + str(runs))
        if e3.get() == 0:
            runs = e3.get()
        else:
            pass

########defines the start buttons state and sets i = 0 for the 'runs' counter########
        global Start_state
        i = 0

########when the button is pushed do:########
        if Start_state == True:
############starts loop for 'runs' counter############
            while i < runs:

################prints states of GPIOs and sets state based on checkbutton input, sets dwell and spray time based on entry box input, runs sequentially################
                print('gpio4: ' + str(GPIO4_state))                
                if GPIO4_state == True:
                    GPIO.output(GPIO4, True)
                    time.sleep(spray)
                    GPIO.output(GPIO4, False)
                    Start_state == False
                    time.sleep(dwell)

                print('gpio17: ' + str(GPIO17_state))                
                if GPIO17_state == True:
                    GPIO.output(GPIO17, True)
                    time.sleep(spray)
                    GPIO.output(GPIO17, False)
                    Start_state == False
                    time.sleep(dwell)

                print('gpio27: ' + str(GPIO27_state))    
                if GPIO27_state == True:
                    GPIO.output(GPIO27, True)
                    time.sleep(spray)
                    GPIO.output(GPIO27, False)
                    Start_state == False
                    time.sleep(dwell)

                print('gpio22: ' + str(GPIO22_state))
                if GPIO22_state == True:
                    GPIO.output(GPIO22, True)
                    time.sleep(spray)
                    GPIO.output(GPIO22, False)
                    Start_state == False
                    time.sleep(dwell)

                print('gpio23: ' + str(GPIO23_state))    
                if GPIO23_state == True:
                    GPIO.output(GPIO23, True)
                    time.sleep(spray)
                    GPIO.output(GPIO23, False)
                    Start_state == False
                    time.sleep(dwell)

                print('gpio24: ' + str(GPIO24_state))    
                if GPIO24_state == True:
                    GPIO.output(GPIO24, True)
                    time.sleep(spray)
                    GPIO.output(GPIO24, False)
                    Start_state == False
                    time.sleep(dwell)
                else:
                    pass

################prints end of run + run number for east debug################
                print('end: ' + str(i))

################adds 1 to the 'runs' to reach entry box value################
                i += 1

############end of while loop############
            else:
                pass

####creates checkbutton and links it to button command####
####positions checkbutton in GUI window####
    checkbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="1", command=GPIO4button)
    checkbutton1.grid(row=1, column=1)

    checkbutton2 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="2", command=GPIO17button)
    checkbutton2.grid(row=1, column=2)

    checkbutton3 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="3", command=GPIO27button)
    checkbutton3.grid(row=1, column=3)

    checkbutton4 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="4", command=GPIO22button)
    checkbutton4.grid(row=1, column=4)

    checkbutton5 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="5", command=GPIO23button)
    checkbutton5.grid(row=1, column=5)

    checkbutton6 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="6", command=GPIO24button)
    checkbutton6.grid(row=1, column=6)

####labels checkbutton rows####
    tk.Label(master, text="SOLENOIDS").grid(row=1, column=0)

####creates entry boxes and links them to entry variable####
####positions entry boxes in GUI window####
    tk.Label(master, text="DWELL TIME").grid(row=6,column=7)
    e1 = tk.Entry(master)
    e1.grid(row=6, column=8)

    tk.Label(master, text="SPRAY TIME").grid(row=7,column=7)
    e2 = tk.Entry(master)
    e2.grid(row=7, column=8)

    tk.Label(master, text="RUNS").grid(row=8,column=7)
    e3 = tk.Entry(master)
    e3.grid(row=8, column=8)

####creates start, stop, and exit buttons and links them to respective commands####
####starts while loop####
    Startbutton = tk.Button(master, text="START", bg="green", command=Start) 
    Startbutton.grid(row=10, column=7)

####stops current 'run'####
    Stopbutton = tk.Button(master, text="STOP", bg="red", command=Start) 
    Stopbutton.grid(row=10, column=8)

####exits GUI window####
    Exitbutton = tk.Button(master, text="EXIT", bg="red", command=master.destroy)
    Exitbutton.grid(row=10, column=9)

####still no real idea####
    master.mainloop()                                                            

#sets all GPIO back to original 'off' state#
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I expect to be able to press the stop button and have the GPIOs return to their off state and then be able to hit the start button again and have the program restart at the beginning again.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [mcve] and reduce your code.

Comment: you don't need `else: pass`.

Comment: instead of three lines `i = 0` and `while i < runs: ` and  `i+=1` you can use one line `for i in range(runs)`

Answer (score 0):

If you starts long-running function then you have to run it in thread but it may have no access to GUI.

If you can split function to smaller parts then you can use `master.after(time, next_part)` to run next part and then `mainloop()` has time to update GUI - ie. it has time to run function assigned to button STOP - and it doesn't freeze. `master.after()` can be use instead of `sleep()`.

Or you can use `master.update()` in many places in your function so it will update GUI - `mainloop()` will have time to run function assigned to STOP button. It will not need thread.

To end program you can use boolean variable (ie. `if is_running:`) in many places. Button `STOP` should set `is_running = False` and it should stops running function on `if is_running:`.

Comment: if I use tk.after(time, next_part) what would I actually put in for 'next_part'? is that literally what I would enter or would it be the name of the next step? my steps aren't really named

Comment: the easiest way is to use `tk.update()`. You don't have to split funtion. You have to only put  `tk.update()` in some places - you need ` `tk.update()` in `while` loop before (or after) every `sleep()`

Comment: okay, i will start with that. do you also know what I would do for def Stop(): to have the program end and return to the off states? Is that just an if statement with a gpio.cleanup()?

Comment: in `Stop()` I would set boolean variable `is_running = False` and in `Start()` I would check it in many places and exit function - ie. `if not is_running: gpio.cleanup() return`

Comment: also, tkinter has no attribute 'update'. so the update thing does not work for this. EDIT: it should have been master.update() for my code. i figured it out lol

Comment: my mistake - it has to be `root.update()`. The same with `root.after()`

Comment: for your code it will be `master.update()` and `master.after()`

Comment: how should i check for the is_running variable during start? is that what the update function does?

Comment: use `if` statement to check `is_running` and use `return` to stop function `START`. `master.update()` doesn't stop function - it runs mainloop once and it gets key/mouse events from system, sends events to widgets, check if widget/button was pressed and executes function assigned to button. It also redraw widget in window, check time to run function assigned by `after()`, etc.

Comment: where should the if statement be and how should it be structured? i've tried multiple places and it never seems to take